# Well founded recursion through lists

Tags: termination, lean

I'm trying out Lean for programming, and I'm struggling with the termination checker. Here's the toy I'm playing with:

```hs
inductive JSON where
  | null
  | bool (value : Bool)
  | string (value : String)
  | number (value : Float)
  | object (data : AssocList String JSON)
  | array (elements : List JSON)

inductive JsonType where
  | atom
  | object (fields : AssocList String JsonType)
  | list (elements : JsonType)

def JSON.hasType : JsonType → JSON → Bool
  | JsonType.object fields, JSON.object data => fields.all (checkField data)
  | JsonType.list ty, JSON.array elts => elts.all (JSON.hasType ty)
  | _, _ => false
where
  checkField data key ty : Bool :=
    match data.find? key with
    | none => false
    | some v => v.hasType ty
termination_by checkField data key ty => ty; JSON.hasType ty j => ty
```

If I inline `List.all` and `checkField` so that all the destructors are under one lambda, then the recursion will be structural and accepted. However, I'd like to understand how to make this work so that I can keep some code modularity.

I tried defining a measure that I could use to set up the `<` relation, but that takes me right back to the termination checker:

```hs
def JSON.measure : JSON → Nat
  | JSON.array elements => 1 + elements.foldl (fun m (elt : JSON) => max m elt.measure) 0
  | JSON.object data => 1 + data.foldl (fun m _ v => max m v.measure) 0
  | _ => 1
```

Another idea is to define `R` so that objects are greater than their values and lists are greater than their elements, then take the transitive closure of that and use WF with that relation, but that's outside my reach to write

Answer (score 1):

Well, this kind of blew up, but at least I feel there's still decent modularity. I kind of brute-forced my way through the multi-motive `JSON.rec` -- if there are good resources to help me understand that, I'd appreciate pointers!

```hs
inductive AssocList.Mem : α → β → AssocList α β → Prop
  | head (k : α) (v : β) (tail : AssocList α β) : AssocList.Mem k v $ AssocList.cons k v tail
  | tail (k : α) (v : β) {k2 : α} {v2 : β} {tail : AssocList α β} (pf : AssocList.Mem k v tail) : AssocList.Mem k v $ AssocList.cons k2 v2 tail

def Std.AssocList.foldMem (as : AssocList α β) (f : δ → (a : α) → (b : β) → AssocList.Mem a b as → δ) (init : δ) : δ :=
  let rec go: δ → (xs : AssocList α β) → ({a : α} → {b : β} → AssocList.Mem a b xs → AssocList.Mem a b as) → δ
  | acc, AssocList.nil, _ => acc
  | acc, AssocList.cons a b tail, pf => go (f acc a b (pf $ AssocList.Mem.head ..)) tail (λ mem => pf $ AssocList.Mem.tail _ _ mem)
  go init as id

def List.foldMem (as : List α) (f : β → (a : α) → List.Mem a as → β) (init : β) : β :=
  let rec go: β → (xs : List α) → ({x : α} → List.Mem x xs → List.Mem x as) → β
  | acc, List.nil, _ => acc
  | acc, List.cons x tail, pf => go (f acc x (pf $ List.Mem.head ..)) tail (λ mem => pf $ List.Mem.tail _ mem)
  go init as id

inductive JSON where
  | null
  | bool (value : Bool)
  | string (value : String)
  | number (value : Float)
  | object (data : AssocList String JSON)
  | array (elements : List JSON)

namespace JSON
  inductive ChildOf : JSON → JSON → Prop
    | array (elt : JSON) (elts : List JSON) : (mem : List.Mem elt elts) → ChildOf elt (JSON.array elts)
    | obj (key : String) (val : JSON) (data : AssocList String JSON) : (mem : AssocList.Mem key val data) → ChildOf val (JSON.object data)

  instance: WellFoundedRelation JSON where
    rel := ChildOf
    wf := WellFounded.intro $ @JSON.rec
      (fun j => Acc ChildOf j)
      (fun data => ∀ (key : String) (val : JSON) (_ : AssocList.Mem key val data), Acc ChildOf val)
      (fun elts => ∀ (elt : JSON) (_ : List.Mem elt elts), Acc ChildOf elt)
      (Acc.intro _ (fun y childOfNull => by cases childOfNull))
      (fun _ => Acc.intro _ (fun y childOf => by cases childOf))
      (fun _ => Acc.intro _ (fun y childOf => by cases childOf))
      (fun _ => Acc.intro _ (fun y childOf => by cases childOf))
      (fun data ih => Acc.intro (JSON.object data) fun val childOf => by
        cases childOf
        case obj => apply ih; assumption)
      (fun elts ih => Acc.intro (JSON.array elts) fun elt childOf => by
        cases childOf
        case array => apply ih; assumption)
      (fun k v mem => by cases mem)
      (fun k v tail ihv iht k2 v2 mem => by
        cases mem
        case head => assumption
        case tail => apply iht; assumption)
      (fun elt mem => by cases mem)
      (fun head tail ihh iht h mem => by
        cases mem
        case head => assumption
        case tail => apply (iht h); assumption)
end JSON
```